# Can I still do I sticky (pinned down) horizontal nav bar if I have a clickable logo on the left side?

Tags: html, css, navigation, sticky

How do I add a logo to my unordered list so that I can turn the whole bar into a sticky nav bar? I've been searching around the internet on how to do this and have given up. I'm turning you to for advice.

I have a basic navigation set up on my current page with just three links (the logo is not clickable yet), and I want to make them all part of my navigation bar. Right now the three bullet points act separately from the logo. I want them all to move and act as one bar. I want this bar to be pinned when you scroll down the page. How do I accomplish this? 
The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta      name="keywords" content="critical theory, mass media, marketing online, mass marketing, social media marketing, viral marketing, viral coefficient, new media, social media" />
<meta name="description" content="Tips & Tricks in Social Media Marketing: A Guide to Viral Marketing" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<title> Viral Marketing A-Z | A Critical Guide to New Media</title>
<link href="newmedia.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
<!--style1 {font-family: MyriadPro-Regular, 'Myriad Pro Regular', MyriadPro, Myriad Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif}-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="logo">
<p align="left"><img src="C:\Users\user\Desktop\virael\assets\virael-logo.jpg" 
alt="logo"/></p>
</div>
<div id="menu">
<ul><p align="right">
<li><a class="button" href="#">Media</a></li>
<li><a class="button" href="#">Resources</a></li>
<li><a class="button" href="#">Blog</a></li>
</p>
</div>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
#logo{
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right top;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
float: left;
margin: 0px 30px 0px 25px;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

```
#menu {
float: both; 
overflow: hidden;
```

}

```
ul {
float: left;
list-style-type:none;
text-align:center;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

}

```
li {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
```

}

```
a:link, a:visited {
font-family: MyriadPro-Regular, 'Myriad Pro Regular', MyriadPro,             

'Myriad Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
display: block;
font-size: 18pt;
font-weight: bold;
width: 256px;
color: black;
background-color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 16px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: capitalize;
```

}

```
a:hover, a:active {
color: purple;
```

}

Comment: you're whole div#menu is very wrong.. you shouldn't a P tag an immediate child of a UL (only li's), plus you're closing the #menu before the UL.. In Any case when you get your HTML valid, why not just put all you need inside of #menu including your nav and logo and then position fix that to the top?

Comment: What would be the best line of code to add as an li for the first child which will be the logo? I'm struggling to figure out: Will it look like this: <li><img src="C:\Users\user\Desktop\virael\assets\virael-logo.jpg" 
alt="logo"/></p>

Comment: You can either have your logo inside an li as a part of your list.. or have it in an a tag outside the ul.. I usually like to separate the logo from the nav.. since it's not really a part of the navigation.. but that's just my preference. I don't understand how this affects a sticky.. you can just wrap this content with a wrapper and position it..

Comment: I want to do whatever makes it easier for me make the navigation sticky...

Comment: I'll try to give you the basics in an answer below..

Comment: tyty. i appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it goes:

### HTML

```
<div id="menu" class="sticky">
    <div class="inner">
        <a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="C:\Users\user\Desktop\virael\assets\virael-logo.jpg" alt="logo"/></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="button" href="#">Media</a></li>
            <li><a class="button" href="#">Resources</a></li>
            <li><a class="button" href="#">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.sticky { position:fixed; height:75px; width:100%; top:0; left:0;}
.sticky .inner { width:75%; margin:0 auto;}
.inner:after    { clear:both; content:""; height:0px; visibility: hidden; display:block;}
.sticky .logo   { float:left;}
.sticky ul      { float:right;}
.sticky ul li   { display:inline-block;}
```

Notice this would have your sticky going across the screen, and inner would be a layout block that'll center, ofcourse change the styling and width according to your needs. let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks alot! I'll play around with it and let you know if I have further questions. It looks right though.

Comment: .inner:after    { clear:both; content:""; height:0px; visibility: hidden; display:block;} what does this line do?

Comment: since I am using float:right and left on the elements inside of .inner, I'm using the :after pseudo element to insert a 'clear' after the floats.. this basically gives .inner the height of the floats.. you can read about it here: http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

Comment: If I want to edit the background color of the whole menu, I would add background-color to .sticky, no?